# Creating a function to take in dataframe name and column in R

Tags: r, function, r-mice

I would like to create a function that will let me input the dataframe name and column and return the rowmeans of its imputation values (have already carried out imputation through mice for each of the columns

```
#fillNA values for columns
fillna_func <- function(data, col){
  df <- data.frame(rowMeans(imp_model$imp$col))
  brf <- data.frame(data[, col])
  colnames(brf) <- "col2"
  colnames(df) <- "col2"
  brf$col1 <- rownames(brf)
  df$col1 <- rownames(df)
  setDF(brf[df,col2_ :=i.col2,on=.(col1)])
  }
brfss2013$X_bmi5 <-  fillna_func(brfss2, "X_bmi5" )
brfss2013$X_bmi5 <-  fillna_func(brfss2, "pa1min_" )
```

However this is the traceback I receive:

```
Error in rowMeans(imp_model$imp$col) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions 
4.
stop("'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions") 
3.
rowMeans(imp_model$imp$col) 
2.
data.frame(rowMeans(imp_model$imp$col)) 
1.
fillna_func(brfss2, "X_bmi5")
```

Comment: Okay, where do you define `imp_model`? It's not in the function, so right away you are reaching out of scope, generally a bad practice (bad in terms of testing, reproducibility, and side-effect). Generally, functions should only get to deal with data that was explicitly passed to it. (I'm asserting my preference for functional programming here, but I think it's a fundamental habit in situations like this.)

Comment: You're trying to do rowmeans  on a vector. What do you expect to get?

Comment: also, assuming `imp_model$imp$col` is trying to reference the variable col that was passed, you need to make it `imp_model$imp[,col]`.

Comment: @iod tried that already

Comment: I'm not saying that will fix your problem - your problem is that you're trying to apply rowMeans on a vector rather than on a matrix. I'm just pointing out that in addition, you also need to use [,col] instead of $col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issues using the following code:

```
fillna_func <- function(data, column){
  df <- data.frame(rowMeans(imp_model$imp[[column]]))
  brf <- data.frame(data[[column]])
  colnames(brf) <- "col2"
  colnames(df) <- "col2"
  brf$col1 <- rownames(brf)
  df$col1 <- rownames(df)
  setDF(brf[df,col2_ :=i.col2,on=.(col1)])
  }
brfss2013$X_bmi5 <-  fillna_func(brfss2, "X_bmi5" )
```

wrapping the column number in this [[]] seems to help resolve to directly reference the column I am trying to use in my function